# how can i make intellisense in visual studio keep triggering

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I don't want to have to type ctrl + space to trigger the IntelliSense suggestion. I want to be able to type any key like "a" or "q" and IntelliSense suggestions will automatically pop up. please help

I'm currently coding c++ in visual studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

Please check the settings:Tools > Options **Auto list member** and **Parameter information**.
[image]
Note: I gave a general answer as it is a general question. I can do my best if the detail level of the error is reached.

Comment: Hi! thank you for trying to help me:) I think you misunderstood my problem. lets say I'm typing the word object. when I type "o" a list of suggestions or "autocomplete suggestions" will pop up. but once I type "ob" all the suggestions disappear. i want these suggestions to stay there no matter what I type.